# Get Max length from variable in Array build with dts.variable

Tags: c#, arrays, ssis

I'm trying to send an email with SSIS including a result i have from an SQL Query.  I use a script task to create my email message and I'm kinda stuck with the format of this file.

The variables in my first column are not of equal length and I'm trying to find the largest length so i could have a nice formatted column (equal length on the mail)

I'm trying something like this... (Note that I'm able to send the mail without formatting it)

```
    public void Main()
    {
        Variables varCollection = null;
        string header = string.Empty;
        string message = string.Empty;

        Dts.VariableDispenser.LockForWrite("User::emailmessage4");
        Dts.VariableDispenser.LockForWrite("User::Variable1");
        Dts.VariableDispenser.LockForWrite("User::Variable2");
        Dts.VariableDispenser.GetVariables(ref varCollection);


        //////TEST Extract longest variable lenght
        string compilation = string.Empty;
        string strmaxlenght = string.Empty;
        compilation = string.Format("{0}",varCollection["User::Variable1"].Value);
        int veriflenght = 0;
        int maxlenght = 0;

        veriflenght = compilation.Length;
            if (veriflenght > maxlenght)
            {
                maxlenght = -100 + veriflenght;
            }

                //strmaxlenght = maxlenght.ToString();
                //MessageBox.Show(strmaxlenght);


        //////end TEST


        //Set the header message for the query result
        if (varCollection["User::emailmessage4"].Value == string.Empty)
        {
            header += string.Format("{0," + maxlenght + "} | {1,-10} \n", "blabla1", "blabla2");
            varCollection["User::emailmessage4"].Value = header;
        }

        //Format the query result with tab delimiters
        message = string.Format("{0," + maxlenght + "} | {1,-25} \n",
                                    varCollection["User::Variable1"].Value,
                                    varCollection["User::Variable2"].Value;

        varCollection["User::emailmessage4"].Value = varCollection["User::emailmessage4"].Value + message;


        Dts.TaskResult = (int)ScriptResults.Success;
    }
}
```

So, my problem is that i get an maxlength value for each variable1 instead of the real maxlength in all variable1.

I've also tried a ForEach loop resulting always in a Binary error of some sort.

Comment: Maybe it's something with the string.format ... is there a way to have a diffente column width for each variable in the collection?

Comment: Finally, i realised that i put my script task in a For Each loop in SSIS... so basically, it writes each individual line one at a time... The solution to get the same column width is by doing a SQL query to extract my max lenght by column and input them as variable in the script task...

Comment: Well then, post your solution as an answer, with some detail, then I'll upvote it :)  http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/07/its-ok-to-ask-and-answer-your-own-questions/  Your solution sounds like what I OFTEN do with SSIS: *  **solve the problem in T-SQL** *.  In your case, you can `CONVERT`/`CAST` all inputs for that column to a reliable max length.  (Another example:  ASCII-->Unicode conversion, for SSIS exports to Excel.  To avoid editing SSIS conversions every time a layout changes, I just `CONVERT` all VARCHAR columns to NVARCHAR in T-SQL, then export the NVARCHAR columns.)

Comment: Well i did something similar...

1) Created a new ExecuteSQLTask

Doing a select max(len(****)) from *** where *** (using from and where of my original query.

It returns a singlerow value that i put in a variable

2) In my original ExecuteSQLTask query, i only added one additionnal column giving my new parameter (converted to a string)

3) Now i realized that in C# Script, it counts it's lenght in pixels... i'm currently working on that part